# peoblem with pygame not loading an icon, backhround, and also fill doesn't work

Tags: image, pygame, window, load, fill

i am having an issiue where i want to setup an icon and background to my window but it does not work and i don't know why i tried looking why it doesn't work but i couldn't find anything. Thanks if you help me.
'''
import pygame

```
#must be zaciatok
pygame.init()

#screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

#title
pygame.display.set_caption("a game with one circle")
icon =  pygame.image.load('circle.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
pozadie = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\admin\Pictures\\textures\\grass.png")



#gameloop
running = True
while running:
    #icon
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

    #background
    screen.fill((255,0,0))
    screen.blit(pozadie, (0,0))

    #vypinanie programu
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    '''
```

Comment: You don't need to set an icon every frame, just one time at the start is enough.

Comment: Where do you update the display? `pygame.display.update()`

Comment: If circle.png is too large (over 64x64 maybe), setting that as your icon can silently fail.

Answer (score 0):

Number one, you do not need to set the icon every frame. This may produce a performance issue(unless you are changing the icon every frame)
Number two, you are not calling `pygame.display.update()`. This updates the screen and shows all the sprites you have.
Number Three, the dimensions of the circle image might cause Pygame to glitch out a bit. Try using another smaller image and see if it works. Yo can also call `Pygame.transform` If you want to make the image smaller without editing the image itself.